# Run two gradle subproject tasks simultaneously

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a monorepo setup such as:

```
monorepo
 build.gradle
 /api
   build.gradle
 /webapp
   build.gradle
```

I've two separate tasks which build and run a development server: `:api:bootRun` and `:webapp:runDev`.

Is it possible to get these two tasks to run in parallel? They are not dependent on each other until the build task `bootJar` is run - which is outside the scope.

I'm currently trying to work around this using `GPars`, but to no avail:

```
tasks.register("dev") {
    def tasksToRun = ['api:bootRun', 'webapp:runDev']

    GParsPool.withPool { ExecutorService svc -> 
        tasksToRun.each { taskToRun ->
            svc.submit({runDevTaskFromProject(tasksToRun)})
        }
    }
}

def runDevTaskFromProject(String projectTask) {
    try {
        String[] components = projectTask.split(':')
        GradleRunner.create()
            .withProjectDir("$projectDir/" + components[0])
            .withArguments(components[1])
            .forwardOutput()
            .build()
    } catch (Exception e) {
        println "Run Failed " + e
        return
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this - or do I need to write something based on the `Workers API` to facilitate this?

Comment: if your tasks are not dependent on each other, they should be eligible to be ran in parallel , did you try to enable parallel execution? (disabled by default ) https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/performance.html#parallel_execution

Comment: It's possible to give Gradle multiple tasks to run. What happens when you run `./gradlew :api:bootRun :webapp:runDev`?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I don't need do any magic as I was proposing in the question; the code below executes the two in parallel (or seemingly so):

```
tasks.register('dev') {
    dependsOn 'api:bootRun'
    dependsOn 'webapp:runDev'
}
```

and can be called using `gradle dev`